# What does the CSS rule "clear: both" do?

Tags: css, css-float

What does the following CSS rule do:

```
.clear { clear: both; }
```

And why do we need to use it?

Comment: When you are using CSS `float` and want next element below, not on right or left.

Comment: No floating elements allowed on the left and the right side of a specified element when the element is used with clear:both

Answer (score 708, accepted):

I won't be explaining how the floats work here (in detail), as this question generally focuses on *Why use `clear: both;` OR what does `clear: both;` exactly do...*

I'll keep this answer simple, and to the point, and will explain to you graphically why `clear: both;` is required or what it does...

Generally designers float the elements, left or to the right, which creates an empty space on the other side which allows other elements to take up the remaining space.

## Why do they float elements?

Elements are floated when the designer needs 2 block level elements side by side. For example say we want to design a basic website which has a layout like below...

[image]

[**Live Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ps5vx/) of the demo image.

Code For Demo

```css
/*  CSS:  */

* { /* Not related to floats / clear both, used it for demo purpose only */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

header, footer {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    height: 100px;
}

aside {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    height: 300px;
}

section {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    height: 300px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<header>
    Header
</header>
<aside>
    Aside (Floated Left)
</aside>
<section>
    Content (Floated Left, Can Be Floated To Right As Well)
</section>
<!-- Clearing Floating Elements-->
<div class="clear"></div>
<footer>
    Footer
</footer>
```

**Note:** *You might have to add `header`, `footer`, `aside`, `section` (and other HTML5 elements) as `display: block;` in your stylesheet for explicitly mentioning that the elements are block level elements.*

### Explanation:

I have a basic layout, 1 header, 1 side bar, 1 content area and 1 footer.

No floats for `header`, next comes the `aside` tag which I'll be using for my website sidebar, so I'll be floating the element to left.

> Note: By default, block level element takes up document 100% width,
>   but when floated left or right, it will resize according to the
>   content it holds.

1. [Normal Behavior Of Block Level Element](http://jsfiddle.net/cpEYu/)
2. [Floated Behavior Of Block Level Element](http://jsfiddle.net/cpEYu/1/)

So as you note, the left floated `div` leaves the space to its right unused, which will allow the `div` after it to shift in the remaining space.

1. [`div`'s will render one after the other if they are NOT floated](http://jsfiddle.net/tUGV7/)
2. [`div` will shift beside each other if floated left or right](http://jsfiddle.net/tUGV7/1/)

Ok, so this is how block level elements behave when floated left or right, so now why is `clear: both;` required and why?

So if you note in the layout demo - in case you forgot, [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ps5vx/) it is..

I am using a class called `.clear` and it holds a property called `clear` with a value of `both`. So lets see why it needs `both`.

I've floated `aside` and `section` elements to the left, so assume a scenario, where we have a pool, where `header` is solid land, `aside` and `section` are floating in the pool and footer is solid land again, something like this..

[image: Floated View]

So the blue water has no idea what the area of the floated elements are, they can be bigger than the pool or smaller, so here comes a common issue which troubles 90% of CSS beginners: why the background of a container element is not stretched when it holds floated elements.  It's because the container element is a **POOL** here and the **POOL** has no idea how many objects are floating, or what the length or breadth of the floated elements are, so it simply won't stretch.

1. [Normal Flow Of The Document](http://jsfiddle.net/wcafZ/733/)
2. [Sections Floated To Left](http://jsfiddle.net/wcafZ/734/)
3. [Cleared Floated Elements To Stretch Background Color Of The Container](http://jsfiddle.net/wcafZ/735/)

(Refer <sup>[Clearfix]</sup> section of this answer for neat way to do this. I am using an empty `div` example intentionally for explanation purpose)

I've provided 3 examples above, 1st is the normal document flow where `red` background will just render as expected since the container doesn't hold any floated objects.

In the second example, when the object is floated to left, the container element (POOL) won't know the dimensions of the floated elements and hence it won't stretch to the floated elements height.

[image]

After using `clear: both;`, the container element will be stretched to its floated element dimensions.

[image]

Another reason the `clear: both;` is used is to prevent the element to shift up in the remaining space.

Say you want 2 elements side by side and another element below them... So you will float 2 elements to left and you want the other below them.

1. [`div` Floated left resulting in `section` moving into remaining space](http://jsfiddle.net/N82UD/)
2. [Floated `div` cleared so that the `section` tag will render below the floated `div`s](http://jsfiddle.net/N82UD/1/)

---

### 1st Example

[image]

---

### 2nd Example

[image]

Last but not the least, the `footer` tag will be rendered after floated elements as I've used the `clear` class before declaring my `footer` tags, which ensures that all the floated elements (left/right) are cleared up to that point.

---

#### Clearfix

Coming to clearfix which is related to floats. As already specified by [@Elky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25343280/1542290), the way we are clearing these floats is not a clean way to do it as we are using an empty `div` element which is not a `div` element is meant for. Hence here comes the clearfix.

Think of it as a virtual element which will create an empty element for you before your parent element ends. This will self clear your wrapper element holding floated elements. This element won't exist in your DOM literally but will do the job.

To self clear any wrapper element having floated elements, we can use

```
.wrapper_having_floated_elements:after {  /* Imaginary class name */
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Note the `:after` pseudo element used by me for that `class`. That will create a virtual element for the wrapper element just before it closes itself. If we look in the dom you can see how it shows up in the Document tree.

[image: Clearfix]

So if you see, it is rendered after the floated child `div` where we clear the floats which is nothing but equivalent to have an empty `div` element with `clear: both;` property which we are using for this too. Now why `display: table;` and `content` is out of this answers scope but you can learn more about [pseudo element here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

Note that this will also work in IE8 as [IE8 supports `:after` pseudo](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent).

---

## Original Answer:

Most of the developers float their content left or right on their pages, probably divs holding logo, sidebar, content etc., these divs are floated left or right, leaving the rest of the space unused and hence if you place other containers, it will float too in the remaining space, so in order to prevent that `clear: both;` is used, it clears all the elements floated left or right.

### Demonstration:

```
------------------ ----------------------------------
div1(Floated Left) Other div takes up the space here
------------------ ----------------------------------
```

Now what if you want to make the other div render below `div1`, so you'll use `clear: both;` so it will ensure you clear all floats, left or right

```
------------------
div1(Floated Left)
------------------
<div style="clear: both;"><!--This <div> acts as a separator--></div>
----------------------------------
Other div renders here now
----------------------------------
```

Comment: If you have never heard about floats, I suggest you first read an introduction to floats --- for example, see the link in the next answer. Then come back and read this answer - it will make sense.

Comment: Take note, floats were **not** originally invented to have two block level elements side by side, that's merely the side effect! The original purpose was to allow text to flow around images inline, so you floated the images in either direction.

Comment: Related short answer to refer before reading this, just to get a general idea.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504

Comment: @mr-alien Good example, however in the case of http://jsfiddle.net/N82UD/1/ when you shrink the screen, there's a problem with float and the "cleared" element is not following the flow: http://jsfiddle.net/N82UD/138/ It takes on the space of floated item 2

Comment: @mr-alien these "bugs" like http://jsfiddle.net/N82UD/138/ kept me away from float. I avoid them like Ebola. Perhaps you can help me make peace with floats once and for all.

Comment: @Carlo: An alternative which is used a lot in templates like Twitter Bootstrap for example; is to put `display: inline-block` on an element, and on the parent you can use `text-align: left`, `text-align: center` or `text-align: right` for example.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Just a suggestion, remove `.clear` CSS from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcafZ/4/). There is no use of it right?

Comment: @student Yes, it's not required :)

Answer (score 47):

The [**`clear`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control) property indicates that the left, right or both sides of an element can not be adjacent to earlier floated elements within the same block formatting context. Cleared elements are pushed below the corresponding floated elements. Examples:

#### `clear: none;` Element remains adjacent to floated elements

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: #EEE;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #CEF;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #CEF;
}
.clear-none {
  clear: none;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-left">float: left;</div>
<div class="float-right">float: right;</div>
<div class="clear-none">clear: none;</div>
```

#### `clear: left;` Element pushed below left floated elements

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: #EEE;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #CEF;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
  width: 60px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #CEF;
}
.clear-left {
  clear: left;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-left">float: left;</div>
<div class="float-right">float: right;</div>
<div class="clear-left">clear: left;</div>
```

#### `clear: right;` Element pushed below right floated elements

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: #EEE;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #CEF;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #CEF;
}
.clear-right {
  clear: right;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-left">float: left;</div>
<div class="float-right">float: right;</div>
<div class="clear-right">clear: right;</div>
```

#### `clear: both;` Element pushed below all floated elements

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: #EEE;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #CEF;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #CEF;
}
.clear-both {
  clear: both;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-left">float: left;</div>
<div class="float-right">float: right;</div>
<div class="clear-both">clear: both;</div>
```

#### `clear` does not affect floats outside the current block formatting context

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: #EEE;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #CEF;
}
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #BDF;
}
.inline-block .float-left {
  height: 60px;
}
.clear-both {
  clear: both;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-left">float: left;</div>
<div class="inline-block">
  <div>display: inline-block;</div>
  <div class="float-left">float: left;</div>
  <div class="clear-both">clear: both;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What will happen if we remove `display: inline-block;` css property from this scenario? It will stretch the `inline-block` parent element to its sibling element which has class `float-left`. Which makes "clear does not affect floats outside the current block formatting context" statement wrong. Could some one explain please?

Comment: @SashrikaWaidyarathna: a parent element does not necessarily generate a [block formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) for its children. In your example (a) removing `display: inline-block` means it no longer generates a block formatting context (b) the floats / clears inside that element ***and*** the first float all become part of the same block formatting context (the viewport).

Comment: @SalmanA , thanks for the explanation referring the css specification. I was not aware of the definition of block formatting context.

Answer (score 23):

**[CSS float and clear](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)**

**[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YKDBv/)**

Just try to remove `clear:both` property from the `div` with `class` `sample` and see how it follows floating `divs`.

Answer (score 15):

Mr. Alien's answer is perfect, but anyway I don't recommend to use `<div class="clear"></div>` because it just a hack which makes your markup dirty. This is useless empty `div` in terms of bad structure and semantic, this also makes your code not flexible. In some browsers this div causes additional height and you have to add `height: 0;` which even worse. But real troubles begin when you want to add background or border around your floated elements - it just will collapse because [web was designed badly](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/). I do recommend to wrap floated elements into container which has [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) CSS rule. This is hack as well, but beautiful, more flexible to use and readable for human and SEO robots.

Comment: This other post has more details on `clearfix`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best

Answer (score 3):

When you want one element placed at the bottom other element you use this code in CSS.
It is used for floats.

If you float content you can float left or right... so in a common layout you might have a left nav, a content div and a footer.

To ensure the footer stays below both of these floats (if you have floated left and right) then you put the footer as `clear: both`.

This way it will stay below both floats.

(If you are only clearing left then you only really need to `clear: left;`.)

Answer (score 0):

Basically it clears all the `float` styles where you declare you "clear" className.

```
.clear { clear: both; }
```

So if you have a lot of floating elements within a container, now you dont want the floating effect after "clear" div, you just declare a div as such:

```
<div className="clear"><div>
```

After the above div, following divs below it will not have floating styles. `Both` means floating from both left and right elements.