# CSS layout clear both affects the flow

Tags: html, css

Why the `<h1>` tag with clear both is at the bottom, if get rid of "clear both", it works fine, how can I get it work with clear both?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=gbk"/>
<style>
#left{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    background:#cfc;
}
#main{
    margin-left:210px;
    background:#f9c;
    height:400px;
}
h1{
    clear:both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="main">
    <h1>test</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My answer here will explain you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734

Comment: You need that you H1 is at the top inside #main?

Comment: i think it should be at the top in the main div, and the clear both should not affect the main div's layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions:

**1- Why the  tag with clear both is at the bottom?**

According to [css specs for `clear`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-clear):

> **both**
>       Requires that the top border edge of the box be below the bottom outer edge of any right-floating and left-floating boxes that resulted
>   from elements earlier in the source document.

So the `clear:both;` on `h1` also clears the float on an *earlier* element, which is not even part of the containing `div` of the `h1`.

**2- How can I get it work with clear both?**

If you need to keep `clear:both;` on `h1` and keep it at the beginning of its container `div`, the simplest way is to add `overflow:auto;` to the container.

### Demo

```
#main {
    margin-left:210px;
    background:#f9c;
    height:400px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: could your tell me why overflow auto can break the clear rule?

Answer (score 2):

The comment by Mr. Alien explains why your having your problem, and an easy way to fix it is to add the following code to your CSS, and remove the `clear: both` from your h1 properties:

```
#main:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;

}
```

If you are going to go float crazy, it is easier to just create a clearfix class that you can apply to your elements. [Here is a link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) that describes how to do exactly that.

Comment: but how about if I have some other tag in the main div with clear:both?
can't I use clear:both in any element in the main?

Comment: The `clear: both` property turns the selector into a separator between floated elements.  So any selector that receives the `clear: both` property will go down under the div.  The proper way to clear floats is what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

It is working as it should work.
The layout affected is the one of the H1. Not the layout of main.
W3c says.. **"The clear property indicates which sides of an element's box(es) may not be adjacent to an earlier floating box."**

So your H1 is going down until it accomplish the constraint.
**It does not matter that H1 is a child of main div**. It must accomplish the constraint as well.

[image]
So if you (for any reason) need to apply clear both to your H1 and at the same time get to avoid the constrain related to your previous floating box, you must absolute position main . You will need a containing block as well so I added the div container relative positioned

You can see it working here in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/awTZE/)

```
#container {
position:relative;
}
#left{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    background:#cfc;
}
#main{
    position:absolute;
    left:210px;
    right:0px;
    background:#f9c;
    height:400px;

}

h1{
    clear:both;    
}
```