# How can I get these divs to appear correctly over the header?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to lay out a set of horizontally aligned divs with a header underneath, but it's appearing as follows:

[image]

This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4cTSK/

What do I need to do to get the divs to appear over the header, like follows?

[image]

```
<div class="horizontal-div-container even-spacing-signature">
    <div>
        <span>Signed by the Client: ______________________ </span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>Signed by the Engineer: _____________________</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="horizontal-div-container even-spacing-signature">
    <div>
        <span>Date: ______________________ </span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>Date: _____________________</span>
    </div>
</div>

<h1>
    Appendix 3, Client Information
</h1>


h1 {
    background: #000096;
    color: #FFF;                
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.horizontal-div-container div {
    float: left;
    clear: none;
}

.even-spacing-signature div
{
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear after you use your floats. I've updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cTSK/2/) to use the ['micro clearfix hack'](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/). See the code below:

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

And then wrap your two floats in a div with the `.cf` class:

```
<div class="cf">
    <div class="horizontal-div-container even-spacing-signature">
        <div>
            <span>Signed by the Client: ______________________ </span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <span>Signed by the Engineer: _____________________</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="horizontal-div-container even-spacing-signature">
        <div>
            <span>Date: ______________________ </span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <span>Date: _____________________</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your floating elements using `clear: both;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hj7fH/)

Or wrap your floating elements inside a `div` and use `overflow: hidden;`

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/hj7fH/1/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="horizontal-div-container even-spacing-signature">
    <div>
        <span>Signed by the Client: ______________________ </span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>Signed by the Engineer: _____________________</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="horizontal-div-container even-spacing-signature">
    <div>
        <span>Date: ______________________ </span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>Date: _____________________</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<h1>
    Appendix 3, Client Information
</h1>

.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

For more info on clearing floats, read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734) answer of mine