# Can't align this #container div to Center

Tags: css, html, alignment, center

I spend the whole afternoon searching, trying many ways but they all don't work. What I want to do is align the div with id="container" (which contain my drop-down menu) to the center of the page.
Here's my code: http://jsbin.com/ilupuf/2/

Comment: It's clearing the floats issue, refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dante, take a look at this:

http://jsbin.com/ilupuf/23/edit

You just have to adjust the menu's width - you didn't specify whether it should have fixed width or not, so I assumed that it doesn't have to stretch to fit the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: left;` and then it centers nicely.

Answer (score -1):

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1024px;
    min-width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

add this class in the css