# clear both is not working after display table

Tags: html, css

I have following html

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</idv>
</div>

<div id="other">some</div>
```

And this is the css

```
#one, #two{
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    height: 47px; 
    background: red;
}

#parent
{
    display:table;
    border-collapse: separate; 
    border-spacing: 10px 0;
}
#other{
    background: blue;
    height: 200px;
}
```

As described in the question the clear both is not working but behaving like before div as if table-cell. The solution for this is to remove `display: table;`. But I would like to know is there any idea without removing `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` from `#one,#two` divs.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rbrt8/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo.. You should've seen the red syntax on the js fiddle

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rbrt8/1/)

This here

```
<div id="two">two</idv>
```

Should be

```
<div id="two">two</div>
```

> Note: You've not used `clear: both;` in your demo, and you don't even
>   require it, as you are not floating the elements, `display: table;` just changes the 
>   display of the elements rendered, yes it does make them inline because of `table-cell` 
>   doesn't mean they need to be cleared. You need to use `clear` property only when you've 
>   floating elements.

For more info on [`clear: both;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734)