# left padding on anchor tag

Tags: html, css, css-float

i have a jsfiddle below with an example of my links displayed in a in-line block, what i don't understand is why is there some sort of padding or margin at the start of every anchor tag, maybe someone could help me out, i am not sure if i have missed something but i just cant seem to find out why that padding is there?

This is the html code:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
   <header class="main-header">
            <h1>blah blah blah</h1>
            <nav class="main-nav">
                <ul class="main-nav-links">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Get a Quote</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

This is all the css code:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
}

.main-header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;    
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #41a2cd;
}

.main-header > h1{
    float: left;
    margin: 11px 0 0 5px;
    color: #073a4f;
}

.main-nav-links > li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav-links li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #073a4f;
}

.main-nav-links > li {
    border-right: 1px solid #45b1e1;
}

.main-nav-links li > a:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    /*background-color: #50bae8;*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pDvZt/

Comment: An easy to understand, remove those styles and find out the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `display: inline-block;` it will leave `4px` spacing between the elements, so you need to use `margin-left: -4px;` or consider using `float` instead.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pDvZt/4/) (Using `margin-left: -4px;`)

```
.main-nav-links > li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/pDvZt/5/) (Using `float` property)

```
.main-nav-links > li {
   list-style: none;
   float: left;
}
```

> Note: Don't forget to clear your floating elements if you use `float:
>   left;` for `li` property.

---

Edit: I would like to specify that inorder to prevent this behavior you can also modify your markup(if you've access to it) than you can line up your `li` elements so that white space between the elements won't be there anymore, for example

```
<ul>
   <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: when you say clear your floating elements what do you exactly mean? and how would i do it because now it all works but when i zoom in and out on my window my containers shift and i think it is because i have not cleared them.

Comment: @user1265535 containers always shrink when you zoom in or out, if you want to know about clearing, just search on google "float clear" and you will get tons of articles else you can refer my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to put

```
<li></li><li></li>
```

in one line. This is actually because the new lines are formatted as spaces.

Comment: +1 Yea I forgot to add this :p but this will mess up his source file if he will get a loooooong single string

Comment: Actually, it's white space in general that adds the 4 pixels offset, not just new lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li></li><li></li>
```

Its the best solution you can get