# why do I need clear:both in the #message declaration

Tags: html, css

If I have `clear:both;` in the `#message` declaration then `padding-top:30px;` in the 
`#message p` declaration will be correct but if I remove the `clear:both` in the
`#message` declaration then `padding-top:30px;` doesn't take effect. 
So why do I need `clear:both` in the `#message` declaration for being able to use 
`padding-top` in the `#message p` declaration.

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    text-align: center;
    width: 768px;
}
#register {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    color: #690;
    background: #BDDB62;
}
#register a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #360;
}
#reg {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 14px;
}
#find {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 14px;
}
#message {
    clear: both;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 110%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background: #92B91C;
}
#message p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#message strong { text-transform: uppercase }
#message a {
    margin: 0 0 0 6px;
    padding: 2px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="register">
    <li id="reg">Not registered? <a href="#">Register</a> now!</li>
    <li id="find"><a href="#">Find a store</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="message">
    <p>
        <strong>Special this week:</strong> $2 shipping on all orders! 
        <a href="#">LEARN MORE</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: probably you need to read http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/css-clear.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [why clear both CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you floating the `register` element? There's no point if it has 100% width, and it causes the problem you are having. Without clearing the following element, the padding on the paragraph slides up under the floated element.

Answer (score 0):

Because `#register` has `float:left;` it is not part of the flow. That means your `#message` element starts at the top of the `body` and only its contents gets pushed at the bottom of `#register`. Now the padding on top of your `p` has plenty room inside `#message` *behind* `#register`.

`clear:both;` forces `#message` to start where there is nothing on both sides of it, not even a float element, so it begins at the bottom of `#register` and your padding does not get behind it.

Comment: No I still don't understand why I must use clear:both to have my padding-top in the "#message p" working.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code:    `#register {float:left;}`

Dont use `float:left;` ever, because it will affect some time in IE.. Instead you use `display:inline-block` or `overflow:hidden`. It will make your code better for all major browsers.

Comment: No I still don't understand why I must use clear:both to have my padding-top in the "#message p" working.

Comment: Visit below link for further...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css