# I still don't understand why I must use clear:both

Tags: html, css

Here is a simplified example to what I had before with markup and style.
I have asked a similar question before but haven't received an answer I fully understand.
You may give a simple example to better explain why I must use `clear:both` to make `padding-top` work.
I do want to really understand `float` and `clear`.

So my question is:
I still can't understand why I must use `clear:both` in the `#message` declaration to make this declaration work

```css
#message p 
{
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>testing</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body 
      {
       text-align: center;
       width: 768px;
     }

     #register 
     { 
       float: left;
       width: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       list-style: none;
       color: #690;
       background: #BDDB62;
     }

     #message 
     {
      clear: both;
      text-align: center;
      background: #92B91C;
    }

    #message p 
    {
      padding-top: 30px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="register">
    <p style="float:left">We float left</p>
  </div>

  <div id="message">
    <p>Paragraph after floated element</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css

Comment: Is `<!DOCTYPE>` allowed by itself? I thought it always had to have `html` after it (for HTML5), making it `<!DOCTYPE html>`...

Comment: @RobbieJW - right, but there's no statement that it is html5, nor that it's compliant with any other specification of HTML. So there's nothing to "allow" or "disallow" it. All we can say, is that `<!DOCTYPE>` will cause quirks mode in browsers.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you need `clear:both` is that your `register` div is floating, and your `message` div is not floating, therefore it is just going to follow `register` along in the layout of the page.

Adding `clear:both` will cause it to essentially break out of that flow and be inserted as a normal `div` would.  The padding is the icing on the cake by moving it down a bit to give you some room.

(Hopefully I understood your question...I didn't get a chance to run your code).

Answer (score 1):

Good question. First remind yourself of this diagram from the CSS spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/images/boxdim.png.

Note that the "content" box is just the inner most text area.

The float rules (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position) say

> ### float:left
>
> The element generates a block box that is floated to the left.
>   **Content** flows on the right side of the box, starting at the top (subject to the 'clear' property).

Now take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/hBwD7/1/ . There's three tests there. Test one, shows what happens when the float is only half the available width. See that the area covered by the `message p` element is depicted by the red box, which includes the padding, surrounds the area of the float element. From the perspective of the padding, the float doesn't exist at all. Because it's only the *content* that flows around the float.

Test two shows that if we increase the padding, eventually the content will drop down under the float.

Test three shows that increasing the width of the float to 100% doesn't change things. from the perspective of the padding, the float doesn't exist. So the padding is simply covered by the float. The float though, can't cover the content, so it appears immediately below the float.

However, if you add `clear:both`, (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control) then an additional rule applies:

> ### clear:both
>
> Requires that the top border edge of the box be below the bottom outer
>   edge of any right-floating and left-floating boxes that resulted from
>   elements earlier in the source document.

The top border edge of the `message` must be now be entirely below the float, The border box contains the padding box, so the padding must start below the float, and the 30px of top padding is shown above your text content.

Comment: excellent explanation. Now I really understand why my example behaved the way it did.