# grouping elements with div and applying stylesheet for that group

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create few divisions and apply different background for each division but my code is not working as expected.

### HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="div1">Im in div-1</div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.main{
    background-color:red;
}
#div1 {
    height:200px;
    width:100px;
    float:left
}
#div2 {
    height:200px;
    width:500px;
    float:left
}
```

When I set the background color for each id, it's working as expected but when I set for the class it's not working.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12871734/1542290) and you'll understand why...

Answer (score 4):

It works, you don't see it because your floating divs are not wrapped by the parent.

Add `overflow:hidden` to the parent div

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XVYeF/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Here U can achieve this by using floated divisions (divs) clearing without using structural markup. It is very effective in resolving layout issues and browser inconsistencies without the need to mix structure with presentation.

Read this

http://perishablepress.com/lessons-learned-concerning-the-clearfix-css-hack/

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Try this -

```
<div class="main clearfix">
    <div id="div1">Im in div-1</div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

In your CSS - Add this

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XVYeF/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `overflow:hidden;` to the parent div, so it should look like this:
`.main{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:red;
}`