# Correct way to position elements using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

Hi I want to position my navigation next to my site name in the header, however its proven to be difficult and I have had to use position:absoutle and margins but I have to go into the minus numbers to get this to appear correctly.

I was wondering if there was an easier way to make these appear side by side?

Click here to view the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sRmpM/1/)!

Or view my code below:

index.html

```
<header>
<h1>iManage</h1>
 <nav>
    <ul class="maina">
        <li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="Settings">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
  </header>
```

style.css

```
header {
 width:auto;
height:50px;
background-color:#374348;
 }

header > h1 {
font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:left;
color:#FFF;
padding:10px;   
}


.maina > li  {
display:inline; 
list-style:none;
}

header > nav {
text-align:center;
width:300px;
height:auto;
border:medium #999;
 position:absoulte;
top:0;
margin: -50px 0px 0px 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is the correct way to do so...

Explanation: You need to `float` your `h1` to the `left`, same goes for `nav` element as well, now what `float` will do? It will `float` your element to the `left` here, which will create an empty space to the right of the floated element, which will make some space for your `nav` to shift up, and than am using `.clear:after` to self clear the parent element, you can use `overflow: hidden;` too instead of `.clear:after`(cuz IE will spoil your game here)...

You can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734) answer of mine which will explain you a concept for clearing your floating elements using `clear: both;` and why you need to clear them.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sRmpM/2/)

```
header {
    width:auto; /* You don't need this too */
    height:50px;
    background-color:#374348;
}

header > h1 {
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    float: left;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:10px;   
}


.maina > li  {
    display:inline; 
    list-style:none;
}

header > nav {
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    border:medium #999;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.clear:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Tips: Generally you would like to have `margin` and `padding` on your menu items, I would like to suggest you to use `display: inline-block;` instead of `block`, also you can get rid of `>` if you really don't find a need to use that.

---

Last but not the least, you are using `header` which is HTML5 element, so make sure you are using HTML5 Reset stylesheet, which will declare other elements like `footer`, `aside`, `nav` as `display: block;` say for example [HTML5 Doctor Stylesheet Reset](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/)

Comment: thanks that's perfect! will accept the answer in 7 mins won't let me do it right now but +1 in the meantime for a great answer @Mr.Alien

Answer (score 0):

you can use float:left; to get this easier, learn about this here:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: better use the official source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-float ;I dislike w3schools coz at first glance it looks so official whilst it is indeed not ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can set both the 'h1' and the 'nav' to display: inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, firstly you can set both the H1 and Nav elements to float:left, but remember to clear:both on the element following the header tag. Remove the Position:absolute, the top:0 and the Margin and you should be good to go.

Let me know how you get on.
AJ