# how to fix a div position close to the right border of the active window

Tags: css, html

I am trying to stack to elements : div and span.I want them to be ordered as a list and it is fine but when the length of the text in the span gets changed it also changes the position of the div above it.

Here is an example:

```
<div style="top: 25px; left: 200px; display: block;">
...
<span id="selectedSearchedItem">This is a span that changes its text dynamically</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W4ZNJ/

I want the part with the button and the textbox to be always at the same offset from the right border and when the text length changes not to afect the controls above.

Answer (score 0):

float it to right and add a margin to right

Comment: Then they both go on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a style like this:

```
style="float:right; margin-right: 5px;"
```

EDIT:

You can wrap your div and span inside a , like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>    
        <div class="block-controls">

            <span id="navigation-text-matches-title" style=" width:auto;">Menu</span>

            <input id="button1" type="button" style="width: 90px; " value="Button1" />

            <input id="textbox1" type="text" style="width: 50px; left: 50px;"/>  
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span id="selectedSearchedItem">This is a span that has dynamically changing text</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But this way they show on the same row.I want them to be on two seperate.

Comment: But I think that this way the div is going to be always align with the beggining of the span.I am trying to set the <div> on a fixed position from the right border and let the span expands without affecting the positioning of the div.

Comment: Use margin-left then along with my suggestion.

Comment: where do I have to use margin-left ? on which element do I have to apply it ? I have tried many options but they show up on the same line or just keep on having the same beggining position.

Comment: On your block-controls div.

Comment: unfortuantelly it is not working.They keep on having the same start point which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Maybe the size of the div is the same as the size of the span. Have you tried setting the width of the div to be smaller, so your margin-left will be applied?

Comment: I changed the div with span and I set its width explicitly to 480(what the actual is) but it still goes at the same starting point with the text.

Answer (score 0):

set positioning property to fixed.
also set overflow attribute equal to hidden or scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want. As Lajos Arpad mentioned you add the float/margin-right to position the button/textbox.
The only extra thing i'm adding here is a div element between your div/span with the clear property set to both.

```
<div class="block-controls">

    <span id="navigation-text-matches-title" style=" width:auto;">Menu</span>

    <input id="button1" type="button" style="width: 90px; " value="Button1" />

    <input id="textbox1" type="text" style="width: 50px; left: 50px;"/>  
</div>
<div class="clearFloats"></div>
<span id="selectedSearchedItem">This is a span that has dynamically changing text</span>

<style>
    .block-controls
    {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .clearFloats
    {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBKEP/)

If you want to find a little bit about how clear:both works i suggest looking at:
[What does the CSS rule clear: both do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css)