# Why is height:auto not working on 2 floating elements?

Tags: html, css

The `div#inner1` and `div#inner2` are inside the `div#outer`, but still the height of `div#outer` shows as 0px with `height:auto`.

How do I get the height of the child elements for the outer div?

This is my code:

```css
#outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background: #ccc;
}

#inner1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
}

#inner2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner1"></div>
  <div id="inner2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734)

Comment: Set 100% instead of auto

Comment: As far as the solution goes, here's the answer - http://jsfiddle.net/k8Zmc/

Comment: why i dont get any answers?

Comment: @user2791037 because I already answered :) duplicating the same answers won't make sense right?

Comment: Here's detailed explanation and examples of "clearfix" solution, suggested by Mr. Alien: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Float the outer div. that will cover your all height, whatever the inner divs holding heights.  But if you will provide your inner div float property. then i will suggest you to use the hack clearfix..

```
    /* Assuming this HTML structure:

    <div class="clear">
        <div class="floated"></div>
        <div class="floated"></div>
        <div class="floated"></div>
    </div>
*/

.clear:before, .clear:after {
    content: "\0020";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.clear:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

> try this it will sure work

Answer (score 38):

Add `overflow:auto` to the div with id `outer`. This will solve your problem.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hta2A/)

Comment: Great answer! Just exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I have to thank you after 5 years of you response, and in the this period of corona virus, you save me from a very long headache