# How to get my div boxes to go together

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML and CSS, I want to know why my left-nav div shows up underneath the content-box div. I would like them to be side by side.

Please don't flame me, I'm sure this is a stupid question but I haven't worked very much in CSS and I'm trying to learn.

```
    @charset "utf-8";
   /* CSS Document */

 #header {
height: 250px;
width: 728px;
border: dashed #000;
text-align:center;
font-family:Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
font-size:12px;
}

#footer {
height: 28px;
width: 728px;
border: dashed #000;
text-align:center;
font-family:Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
font-size:12px;
}

#left-nav {
height: 500px;
width: 150px;
border: dashed #000;
text-align: center;
font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
font-size: 14px;
position: relative;

}

#content-box {
height: 500px;
width: 578px;
border: dashed #000;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-left: 155px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

.

```
<body>

<div id="header">
this is the header
</div>

<div id="content-box">
</div>

<div id="left-nav">
<ul id="left-nav-links">
<li> <a href="#"> Link Item #1 </a></li>
<li> <a href="#"> Link Item #2 </a></li>
<li> <a href="#"> Link Item #3 </a></li>
<li> <a href="#"> Link Item #4 </a></li>
<li> <a href="#"> Link Item #5 </a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="footer">
this is the footer
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Div elements are by default block-level elements. They don't allow you to have multiple elements on the same line.

What you need is for the element to be inline-level. This would allow multiple elements to be "in-line" with each other.

Problem with inline, is you cannot set the height and width as you can a "block" element. So the answer is inline-block. This element flows inline with other inline-block elements but also allows for height and width and such.

So you need to add the CSS `display:inline-block` to both "content-box" and "left-nav" elements.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to:

1. use `float:left` for your sidebar and content. this makes them go to the left side of the line. you should use this when you need two (or more) elements side by side. [read this for a description on how float works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12871734/2808025).
2. move sidebar element to before content.
3. also use `display:inline-block` for your sidebar and content. so they can have width and height.
4. add an element with `clear:both` after them. this clears float on both sides, and allows next elements not to have float.
5. please note that `border-width` is not counted as element `width`, and your content no longer needs a `margin-right` value.

=================================

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    @charset "utf-8";
   /* CSS Document */

    #header {
        height: 250px;
        width: 728px;
        border: dashed #000;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-size:12px;
    }

    #footer {
        height: 28px;
        width: 728px;
        border: dashed #000;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-size:12px;
    }

    #left-nav {
        float:left;
        display:inline-block;
        height: 500px;
        width: 150px;
        border: dashed #000;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #content-box {
        float:left;
        display:inline-block;
        height: 500px;
        width: 572px;
        border: dashed #000;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    #clear{
        clear:both;
    }

    #container{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    body{
            text-align:center;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        this is the header
    </div>


    <div id="left-nav">
        <ul id="left-nav-links">
            <li> <a href="#"> Link Item #1 </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Link Item #2 </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Link Item #3 </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Link Item #4 </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Link Item #5 </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content-box">
    </div>

    <div id=clear></div>

    <div id="footer">
        this is the footer
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In addition to that, it does not allow me to center all of the divs, if I center them only the header and footer are centered how do I center the left-nav and content-box as well?

Comment: it needs a container to be centered, see my updated code, it's now centered! :)

Comment: It seems that the divs are still all stuck to the left and not centered

Comment: @user2880722, clear removes the float for all the proceeding elements. It also anchors any containers so they take up the correct size. Think of it as a nail holding down a sheet of the bottom of a sheet of paper in place

Comment: You can't center floated elements. Inline-block would of been a better option of you need this.

Answer (score 0):

You should give this a try, put those two divs in a wrapper and set the childs' display style to `inline-block` to make the childs inline. It should look similar to this:

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
this is the header
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content-box">
</div>

<div id="left-nav">
<ul id="left-nav-links">
<li> <a href="#"> Link Item #1 </a></li>
<li> <a href="#"> Link Item #2 </a></li>
<li> <a href="#"> Link Item #3 </a></li>
<li> <a href="#"> Link Item #4 </a></li>
<li> <a href="#"> Link Item #5 </a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="footer">
this is the footer
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
       /* CSS Document */

     #header {
    height: 250px;
    width: 728px;
    border: dashed #000;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size:12px;
    }

    #footer {
    height: 28px;
    width: 728px;
    border: dashed #000;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size:12px;
    }

    #left-nav {
    height: 500px;
    width: 150px;
    border: dashed #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    #content-box {
    height: 500px;
    width: 578px;
    border: dashed #000;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 155px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution implies creating a wrapper to contain the columns (left-nav and content) and then, float each of these columns (to the right and left respectively). Check out the CSS below and the fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/torovoltanrex/yrARC/

```
#header {
height: 250px;
width: 728px;
border: dashed #000;
text-align:center;
font-family:Baskerville;
font-size:12px;
margin:0 auto;
}
#wrapper {
width:740px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
}
#footer {
margin:0 auto;
height: 28px;
width: 728px;
border: dashed #000;
text-align:center;
font-family:Baskerville;
font-size:12px;
clear:both;
}

#left-nav {
padding:0;
height: 500px;
width: 150px;
border: dashed #000;
text-align: center;
font-family: Baskerville;
font-size: 14px;
float:left;

}

#content-box {
padding:0;
height: 500px;
width: 578px;
border: dashed #000;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
float:right;
}
```