# Site container won't wrap?

Tags: html, css, border, wrapper

For some reason my container won't wrap a border around the other elements. Now it just wraps  border around the header. Have checked with validators for both css and html but they show no errors. Anyone now what the problem is?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<title>Site Tite in Browser</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen" />   
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"> <!-- Container Start -->
<div id="header">
<div class="site-title">Site Title</div>
<div class="site-description">a description of the site</div>
</div>
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content"> <!-- Content Start -->
<h2>Title</h2>
Sample text
</div> <!-- Content End -->
<!-- Sidebar Start -->
<div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div> <!-- Sidebar End -->
<div id="footer">Copyright &copy [sitename]</div> 
</div> <!-- Container End -->
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
body {
background:#990000;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#container {
width:960px;
background:#fff;
padding:10px;
margin:10px auto 10px auto;
border-width:5px;   
border-style:double;
border-color: #000000;
}

/* Header Start */

#header {
background:url(images/header.jpg) top left repeat-x #fff;
width:960px;
height:150px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.site-title {
color:#fff;
margin:0;
padding:10px;
font-weight:normal;
font-size:24pt;
}

.site-description {
text-align:right;
padding:50px 10px 10px 10px;
color:#fff;
font-size:12pt;
font-weight:bold;
}


/* Menu Start */

#menu {
margin:10px 0 0 0;
padding:0 10px 0 10px;
height:37px;
width:940px;
border:1px #000000;
}

#menu li {
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:inline;
}

#menu li a {
font-weight:bold;
font-size:12pt;
text-decoration:none;
padding:0 10px 4px 10px;
display:block;
margin:0;
line-height:33px;
float:left;
}

#menu li a:hover {
color:#000000;
}



/* Main Content Start */

#content {
margin-top:10px;
width: 500px;
overflow : auto;
float: left;
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px;
}


/* Sidebar Start */
#sidebar {
margin-top: 10px;
width:400px;
height:auto;
float:right;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
background: #ffffff;
border:10px solid #fff;
}

/* Footer Start */

#footer {
clear:both;
width: 950px;
margin-top: 10px;
float: left;
height: 40px;
border-top:1px solid #000000;
color:#000000;
text-align:center;
font-size:12px;
}

/* Format Start */

a {
color:#990000;
}
```

Comment: You need to look up clearfix. It will help with some of your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Floated content does not take up vertical space within the DOM, in fact when you float something you should think of almost lifting it off the DOM. In order to fix this problem you should add a clear at the bottom of your container with floated elements inside.

So at the end of your HTML, you should have something like this.

```
    <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div> <!-- Sidebar End -->
    <div id="footer">Copyright &copy [sitename]</div> 

    <div style="clear:both;"></div> <!-- Clears the floated content -->

</div> <!-- Container End -->
```

For a more advanced and pretty solution "in my opinion", you can check out this link.
[HTML/CSS: Clear floating elements in the middle without adding unneeded tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102120/html-css-clear-floating-elements-in-the-middle-without-adding-unneeded-tags)

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick.
I modified the solution into a div class so I got clean html and css.