# CSS box element positioning

Tags: css

Here I have create one `div` box using css stlye.

Fiddle: [Correct view](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/BskEu)

But if the description is small then content misaligned as below: 
[Misaligned box](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/uECjJ)

i tried changing the position and css values, but no luck.

Can some one tell me how can I keep `footer` part on it's position even if the content is small.

Comment: For everyone who hates codepen as much as me, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5BmLE/

Comment: @ExtPro ROFL, I was making the same in jsfiddle, I tidied up the code, and when I was here, I saw your comment :)

Comment: BTW you are not clearing your floats, `clear: both;` is all you need, read my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12871734/1542290) for detailed info

Comment: setting overflow: hidden; also works.

Comment: To OP: jsfiddle is for debugging, codepen is for showcasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the floats:

```
.footer-working-area {
    clear:both; /* this sets the element flow back to normal */
    background: transparent url(...) left 5px repeat-x; 
                                        /* /\ have some padding for the img */
}
```

Now the footer always stays below the picture, no matter how few text content you have.

Here you have the accordingly [modified example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BmLE/3/).

Comment: thanks buddy, I have one more small issue. Small box which shows `34%` can you please tell me how can I place in middle of top header?

Comment: in fiddle header part does not looks correctly. Please see codepan

Comment: @cyclic I don't know exactly how to handle codepens, but have a look at this: http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/uECjJ ?

Comment: Thanks I could do it by setting top-margin!

Answer (score 0):

You can give your text a min-height...

```
.text { min-height: 110px; }
```

... or a height if you don't expect longer texts

```
.text { height: 110px; }
```

... or clear the floats as Christoph mentioned in an other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add *clearfix* to the `.text` class

```
.text::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5BmLE/2/)**

Comment: I didn't notice that the dotted belt is the part of the footer. Anyway, this is one of the solutions.