# What does an empty value for the CSS property content do?

Tags: css, css-content

```
nav ul:after { 
    content:""; 
    clear:both; 
    display:block;
}
```

What does the `""` value mean on the content property?

Comment: It's a clearfix.. The content is empty. Nonetheless, there is still a difference between that and not setting a content value at all.

Comment: tks for ur quick response.:-)

Comment: see this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

Comment: You shouldn't be downvoting, read his profile, it says beginner, there is no harm if a person is providing some alien code, and tries to understand

Answer (score 5):

It's just a clearfix, which means, if your `ul` elements have floated `li`, than they will be self cleared, it just behaves similar to `overflow: hidden;` but unlike `overflow: hidden;` it wont hide the overflowing content.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4LAV/) (Without clearfix)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4LAV/1/) (With clearfix)

And why you need to `clear` and what you need to clear, for that, you can refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734)

---

As you edited your question, [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property is used with `:before` or `:after` pseudo to embed virtual content on the page, so using `content: "";` means just blank, you are not embedding any character in your page.

Comment: It should be noted that the `content` property is required for the psuedo-element to be rendered at all.