# Button element without text causes subsequent buttons to be positioned wrong

Tags: html, css

I came across an interesting HTML button tag behavior while trying to style a button that has no text inside, only a font icon -- the button without text causes all subsequent buttons which do have text to be pushed down. The issue only appears when the buttons have a `height` attribute specified.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jF8MH/2/)**

```
<header>
    <button><!-- No text here --></button>
    <button>This button is pushed down</button>
</header>

button { height: 40px; }
```

At first I was sure it was due to the font icon inside the first button that did some weird baseline magic, but as you can see from the minimal working example, the behavior is maintained when there is no content at all inside the button.

I can fix this by adding content to the first button, but because my only content is a `<span class="icon user"></span>`, which is a font icon, it does in fact interfere with the font baseline, and positions the button off just a few pixels. This is why I have decided to position the icon inside absolutely, which fixes the original slight positioning issue, but introduces this new one, as the button now acts as if it were empty.

So, the question remains -- how do I avoid positioning issues with empty buttons?

**Note**: it seems that the above only happens on webkit browsers; Firefox positions buttons with text correctly, but pushes the empty ones up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is because the `button` is an `inline` element, which is aligned to *baseline* by default.

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) :

> Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If
>   the box does not have a baseline, align the bottom margin edge with
>   the parent's baseline.

Inorder to align them correctly, use `vertical-align: top;` *(Or `middle`, `bottom` as a value)*

```
button { 
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 5px; 
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jF8MH/3/)

---

On the other hand you can also use zero width space entity [`&#8203;`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jF8MH/4/)

---

This behavior is common with `inline` and `inline-block` elements, if you want to avoid everything above, you can use `float` here, than you won't need the `vertical-align` property as `float` will force the `button` to be *inline* as well as *block level*

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jF8MH/5/) *(Using `float: left;`)*

> **Note**: If you are going with `float`, just make sure you clear them, if you aren't sure what `clear` means, than refer my answer
>   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12871734/1542290) which will explain in detail.

Comment: Thanks, both solutions work great for me! Are there any reasons for preferring one over the other?

Comment: @Elise If you go for second solution, you will have to add the entities in your HTML document, if you prefer CSS, I would suggest you to use `vertical-align: bottom;` instead.. :) and you welcome..

Answer (score 1):

add text to the button and indent the text off the screen. This will solve your problem as well as helping with your SEO as robots indexing your site can register text but not the content of the image.

```
button{
    width:;
    height:;
    display:block;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I do have text inside the button for screen readers, but I am using the trick from [here](http://zerosixthree.se/8-sass-mixins-you-must-have-in-your-toolbox/) (see item 8) to hide it, which causes the text not to take up any actual space.

Comment: the tips you highlight uses absolute positioning which takes the elelment out of the flow, hence the container collapsing. Try the text-indent instead.