# Avoid element overlap when dealing with CSS remainder

Tags: html, css, css-float, fluid-layout

I have a layout involving a `div.left` on the left with a set width of 40px, and a `div.right` on the right with a width of 100% to fill the remaining parent-container space.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left">
        L
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        R
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.parent {
    background: maroon;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    background: green;
    width: 40px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.right {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 50px;
    background: blue;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4REh3/)

Is it possible to achieve this layout (one element with fixed width next to another that fills the remaining space) *without* resorting to the padding method I'm currently using? My problem is that I'd like to use a transparent background on the left-floated element, so the padding hidden beneath those elements would be visible. Also, my current approach doesn't downsize fluidly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to `float: left;` the other element as well..

```
.right {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4REh3/1/)

Also, am using `calc()` here, to deduct the fixed `width` sidebar which is `40px` from `100%` right bar.

[image]

---

As @Krimson [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900219/avoid-element-overlap-when-dealing-with-css-remainder/21900287?noredirect=1#comment33166840_21900287) that you want some space between the element as well, than use `margin`

```
.right {
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4REh3/3/)

Note: In the demo, am using `overflow: hidden;` as a quick fix for clearing floats, but better use `clear: both;` for that, for more information on clearing floats, you can read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734).

---

**Inspected Elements**

[image]

[image]

Comment: This wont work. If you notice. OP is adding a 50px padding and the left bar is only 40px which means he want to a gap in the middle. Adding float to both elements will not give the gap

Comment: You added a margin-left in the demo. The css in your answer didn't have that :|

Comment: @Krimson So that's what am saying, I already answered him what he asked, than he can tweak according to his requirements

Comment: @Krimson Also, if you see in your solution, the element will overflow.. http://jsfiddle.net/7ubS2/1/ where as in mine, it wont http://jsfiddle.net/4REh3/3/

Comment: I guess if u remove the width: 100% in mine u wont get the overflow

Answer (score 1):

What if u change your `.right` to this:

```
.right {
    /* width: 100%; remove width */ 
    margin-left: 50px; /* Margin instead of Padding */
    background: blue;
}
```

## JSFiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ubS2/2/)