# Div positioning - Css

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

Here is the failed [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/anilca/ZeGTF/). I want to have the **buttonCenter** div located in the black box in the following image:

[image]

How do I have to change the css class for **buttonCenter**:

```
#buttonCenter {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:100px;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need `position: relative;` and add `z-index` *(Just for a safer side)* as well..

```
#buttonCenter {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:100px;
    background-color:gray;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeGTF/1/)

Though would like to tell you that the positioning is just weird, you are floating the elements for no good reasons.

For example, you are applying `float: left;` for `#row1`, `#row2` and `#buttonsContainer` which *isn't required* as they take up entire horizontal space.

Don't use `id` to identify each element, better use classes, so that you can share a common `class` between elements holding common styles, because you cannot use same `id` on a single document, they should be unique.

Also, you are using huge margins, consider using `position: absolute;` instead

Comment: @anilca You welcome, and if you are looking to get rid of unnecessary floats, than make sure you clear them using `clear: both;`, especially the `#buttonsContainer` container holding floated elements, read my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css), to know why that's necessary