# Unable to clear float with pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to clear the float with the css pseudo element, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LqKW9/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner1"></div>
</div>
<div id="afterfloat"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    float:left;
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#inner1{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#container:after{
   content: "."; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}

#afterfloat{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to do ? A wild guess would be to add `clear:both;` or `clear:left` to `#afterfloat`.

Comment: +1 I tried the same. I mean clearing float with pseudo elements. didn't work.

Comment: @HamZa I'm trying to repeat solution shown at [All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

Comment: You can check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12871734/3030434)

Comment: HamZa is right - you absolutely do not need a clearfix for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:after` pseudo class in an element does not mean "after the ending tag of that element", it will put after all inner items in an element. So you cannot use it for clear-fixing. Try to use -

```
#afterfloat {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: So, what would be the solution in regards to [All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) ?.

Comment: @Dimt Does seem to be that way, didn't know that. So I guess you just have to [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/LqKW9/8/)...? Or like Iqbal said [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/LqKW9/10/)

Comment: According to [All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) and other sources I should be able to use a pseudo element to clear the float without any extra markup or clearing succeeding element. Is this not valid statement then ?

Comment: @Dimt No. That solution is for another case. If your parent element has float:none; and children has float:left or right, in that case parent element does not grow with the children element. In that case you can use ".clearfix:after" solution, to grow the parent with children element.

Comment: Ah, I see, so instead floating parent to make it to expand to the child's size I can use the pseudo element.

Comment: `:after` is a pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class. Also not sure what you mean by "after all inner items in an element". A single element can only generate a single `:after` pseudo-element for itself.

Comment: @Iqbal _"That solution is for another case"_ I think that is the answer to my question, thanks.

Comment: @BoltClock Probably that is my lacking in English. I meant "At the end, but inside of the element."