# Two elements how to arrange them one after another

Tags: html, css, layout

I have an html file(*index.html*) and a css file(*style.css*), there is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RZm5y/2/ .

*index.html*

```
<html>
<head>
<title>demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="logo">artistLog</div>
    </div>
<div class="topbar">This is the top search/login bar</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="cover" src="img/cover.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="card">Description</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*style.css*

```
html, body {
    background: #343434;
    margin:0px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.nav {
    background: #565656;
    color: #b4b4b4;
    margin-right:0px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border-right:7px solid #2b2b2b;
    width: 86px;
}
.nav .logo {
    background:#353535;
    height:60px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-bottom:1px solid #353535;
}
.topbar {
    background: #1d1d1d;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8d8d8d;
    height: 60px;
    left: 86px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.content {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 120px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 62px;
    padding: 50px 25px 25px 20px;
}
.content .card {
    background: #101010;
    color:#a4a4a4;
    width:250px;
    height:320px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.content .card .cover {
    max-width:250px;
    max-height:140px;
    background: transparent;
    float:left;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

I want the cards inside the content to be showed one after another not one under another when the display is big enough to show minimum 2 cards one after another else show one under another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that simply by `float`ing the cards to a side.

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/RZm5y/4/)**.

```css
.content .card {
    background: #101010;
    color:#a4a4a4;
    width:250px;
    height:320px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    float: left; /* <-- Added declaration */
}
```

Since you have added `overflow: auto;` to the `.content` element, the float is already cleared. However you might want to consider this topic:

- [What does the CSS rule clear: both do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734)

Comment: No point in providing another answer since @hashem already answered it. You may want to consider adding a **display:block;** as well.

Comment: @Chris As the OP has used `<div>` element to create the cards, they  are already block-level elements.

Comment: Thank you guys, i really appreciate your answers!