# Form elements are not properly aligned in firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Please have a look at this test: http://jsfiddle.net/mqvL8/

If I use Chrome or Safari, everything is aligned properly

[image: example with Chrome]

If I do the same thing in Firefox, it looks like this:

[image: example with Firefox]

Any idea why the difference?

I am using div's like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <span class="control-label col-xs-2"><b>Name</b></span>
</div>
```

Each of the titles has a CSS class of `col-xs-2` of which I would assume will make everything properly aligned like Chrome and Safari do. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your fiddle looks fine to me in FF. Did you clear your cache? I'm not seeing any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `clear:both` on form-group

```
.form-group {
    clear:both;
}
```

## [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqvL8/2/)

Comment: Thx! For newbies to CSS like me, some extra info on clear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css