# No background on parent element containing floated elements

Tags: html, css

Good day everyone. I'm a novice with css and I'm trying to float two div tags within one div tag but I'm getting the following

[image: Screen shot of problem]

I gave the parent div tag a light grey background so I know something is wrong somewhere as the background has disappeared just after I floated the div tags.

Here's my css below.

```
.menu.container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

.category {
    float: left;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Even this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734

Comment: You can use bourbon or sass for easier css implementation.
you can take a look at this video how easy this is to build css.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ItNE_DX6Cc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when floating elements the parent container does not recieve information about width or height of the floated elements.

if you just want to align sports and News in a horizinal manner then try the following:

```
.category {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

"display:inline-block" forms a block element that be on one line with another.