# Confusion about how to apply the clear attribute in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm working through a tutorial and I have a form that uses float elements. The form currently has all the labels and input boxes next to each other.

To align the form so that everything is on the left the book teaches me to:

Put-> **clear: left;** as below

```
label {
  float: left;
  width: 5em;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: .5em;
  **clear: left;**
}
input {
  background-color: #CCCCFF;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
```

The way I understand the clear attribute is that if I set it on a floating element, it means that I want nothing to the left/right/both of that element.

Therefore, in my head, instead of putting the clear attribute on the label, putting that **clear:right;** on the input should also work (because then nothing can be on the right side of the input box), but of course it doesn't.

There's a gap in my understanding, can someone please point out why putting the clear:right attribute on the inputs won't work the same as putting the clear:left attribute on the label?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why clear both CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css)

Answer (score 0):

basically the `clear` property kind of overwrites the float.

i prepared this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vlrprbttst/JF7wD/1/

all `div`s are floated to the left. when `float` is applied, they all go next to each other. what if you need to temporary block this behaviour but still need a floated element? that's when you use `clear`

not the best way to explain it but i hope you got it :)

Comment: But why is it that putting the clear:right attribute on the inputs won't work the same as putting the clear:left attribute on the label?

Comment: No man, go back to that guys demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mofeenster/UH7Hp/1/  Take away the clear attribute on the label and do clear:both on the input element. It messes up.

Comment: Hey, if you take clear: left off the labels they won't clear the fields. Don't you want the labels to clear the fields?

Answer (score 0):

The `<input>` and `<label>` elements are *inline* elements by default, so under normal circumstances they do not fill the width of their parent elements and do not require their own line. So having `<input>` elements and `<label>` elements one-after-the-other do not strictly require any floating logic:

```
<form>
    <input type="text"></input><label>test</label>
    <input type="text"></input><label>test</label>
    <input type="text"></input><label>test</label>
</form>
```

Without any CSS, the above markup produces this:

[image: inputs in a line]

The `float:left` CSS is used to force elements out of the *flow* of the document, and hug their adjacent counterparts. It's used mainly on *block* elements. The `clear:left/right/both` then overrides this functionality in order to bring the proceeding elements back into the flow of the document. Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

If you're simply wanting to force `<input>` elements to be on their own line, perhaps you could wrap them in a *block* element like a `<div>`:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="text"></input><label>test</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text"></input><label>test</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text"></input><label>test</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

The above, without any CSS, will produce this:

[image: block elements]

Read about [*inline*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) and [*block*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) elements in order to further your understanding of how elements are positioned naturally within the document.

To summarise, the *float* CSS property is a way of taking an element out of the flow of the document and positioning it to the left or right of *inline* elements. To quote MDN:

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

Comment: "The float:left CSS is used to force elements out of the flow of the document, and hug their adjacent counterparts" - well as far as i know, `float` *was* used to *float* text around an element like news paper articles, which was *misused* for creating layouts since there was no other way back in time. times are changing :)

Comment: @TilwinJoy *float* implies a change in the behaviour of a block-level element. See the quote from MDN at the end of my answer. Yes, it's used to *float* text around an element, but it does this by taking the element out of the document flow.

Comment: But why is it that putting the clear:right attribute on the inputs won't work the same as putting the clear:left attribute on the label?

Comment: @absurdity69 Perhaps that would be an easier question to answer by getting more of an understanding about what you'd *actually* like to achieve. Do you want the `<input>`s and `<label>`s adjacent, and would you like each pair on their own line?

Answer (score 0):

it won't work as you are using `float: left` and want to `clear: left`, not `clear: right`. as demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mofeenster/UH7Hp/1/)

See my code below:

**CSS**

```
label {
  float: left;
  width: 5em;
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: .5em;
  clear: left;
}
input {
  background-color: #CCCCFF;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

**HTML** - ensure the order you want the labels in is correct here too

```
<form>
    <label>test</label><input type="text"></input>
    <label>test</label><input type="text"></input>
    <label>test</label><input type="text"></input>
</form>
```

You can choose to clear both if unsure, however if you are floating left use clear left, not clear right, as there is nothing to clear on the right.

Comment: Yes, if you take away clear:left attribute on the label elements, then the form becomes messed up. The clear:left or even clear:both attribute in the input element doesn't fix the form's appearance - I just don't get why the clear must be on the label element rather than on the input element. Do you understand my issue?

Comment: Hi there, why would you want to take it away?

Comment: I wouldn't but if the clear attribute works then why won't it clear everything to the right of the input boxes thus having the same effect as clear:left on labels?

Comment: Hi, if you apply clear: right to an element, THAT element will clear the element it is next to it, providing that the element next to it is not set to display: block or width: 100% etc. Basically the elements have to be able to stack.. If you want the labels to clear the inputs they must be set to clear left. You can't apply a clear on an element unless you state it in CSS on the element you want to do the clearing.

Comment: Thank you. That vaguely makes sense now. When you refer to "stack", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Arrange items on top of each other, as opposed to next to each other.