# Move a nav which is inside a header to the right side

Tags: html, css, header, nav

I have a `nav` inside my header and I wanted to move the `nav` to the right side of the page. I tried `float:right` but it was not lined up anymore with my header. here is my code:

```
<header>
<nav>
    <h1>my page</h1>
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>blog</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>about</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>contact</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>links</li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
header{
background:#999;
color:white;
padding:15px 15px 0 15px;
}

header h1{
margin:0;
display:inline;
}

nav ul{ 
margin:0;
display:inline;
padding:0 0 0 15px;
}

nav ul li{
background:black;
color:white;
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
padding:5px 15px;

}
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsbin.com/yumodu/1/edit

Comment: Looks like `float:right` works...add that in you CSS under `nav ul` http://jsfiddle.net/dtt7ehd4/

Comment: The point is that you should clear the float in order for the parent (the `header`) to be as tall as its floated child (the `ul`). You could do that by using `::after` pseudo-element like so:
`header:after { content: ""; display: block; clear: both; }`

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add `inline-block` properties to your `nav` and `header` elements. Also add `width:100%` to your header so it will be full size. Of course don't forget about `float:right` to your `nav`.

Also move your `h1` outside the `nav`.

There is correct code:

```
header{
background:#999;
color:white;
padding:15px 15px 0 15px;
width:100%;
}

header h1{
margin:0;
display:inline;
}

header, nav {
display:inline-block;
}

nav {
float:right;
}

nav ul{ 
margin:0;
display:inline;
padding:0 0 0 15px;
}

nav ul li{
background:black;
color:white;
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
padding:5px 15px;

}
```

Comment: `There is correct code` I don't think so, since it moves the `<h1>` element to the right side and also adds a horizontal scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/wnrkec54/1/

Comment: tested on FF and Chrome and i see no horizontal scroll.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide an online demo on jsfiddle or ant other online editors.

Comment: Ok, thanks for advise. I'll try to use jsfiddle next time. I'm new here.

Answer (score 0):

As I [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353463/how-to-move-a-nav-that-is-inside-a-header-on-a-specific-spot#comment39529615_25353463), you should clear floats at the end of the container (`header` or `nav` in this particular case) to stretch background color of the container.

That's because the container has no idea about its floated children or what the height of the floated elements are, Hence it won't stretch.

You can find a lot of discussion **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734)**.

Clearing floats can be done either by using the `::after` pseudo-element:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/yumodu/5/edit)**

```css
header:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Or by appending a `<div>` element having a `.clear` class to the container:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/yumodu/4/edit)**

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1>my page</h1>
    <ul>
      ...
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</header>
```

```css
.clear { clear: both; }
```

Besides, note that `<a>` is NOT a valid child for `<ul>` element. You should place your anchor tags within list items (`<li>` elements) when you're working with ordered/unordered lists.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<header>
<nav>
<h1>my page</h1>
<ul>
    <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>blog</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>about</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>contact</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>links</li></a>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
header{
background:#999;
color:white;
padding:15px 15px 0 15px;
}

header h1{
margin:0;
display:inline;
}

nav ul{ 
margin:0;
display:inline;
padding:0 0 0 15px;
float:right;
margin-top:-5px
}
nav ul:after{clear:both;}

nav ul li{
background:black;
color:white;
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
padding:5px 15px;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnrkec54/) here

Comment: Using `display:inline;` and `float:right;` at the same time is pointless. Besides, you didn't clear the float properly as `nav ul:after{clear:both;}` do nothing. And while `margin-top:-5px` is aligned the navigation vertically in a valid position here, it's absolutely not a correct solution.

Comment: wow, I forgot some code he left, sorry, the world will fall apart. The fact remains: Does the solution work? yes. Thus, it's TO THE VERY LEAST a QUITE CORRECT SOLUTION. TO THE VERY LEAST.