# Div floated left and div floated right causing background to disappear

Tags: html, css, background, css-float

I need the footer to have an image floated to the left and some more text (an inline `ul` with links) floated to the right of the footer.

Here is the CSS & HTML:

```css
footer {
   clear: both;
   background: #113551;
   width: 90%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
.left-foot {
   float: left;
}
.right-foot {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<footer>
   <div class="left-foot">
      <p> derp 1</p>
   </div>

   <div class="right-foot">
      <p>derp2</p>
   </div>
</footer>
```

It works-ish, however the background color of the footer does not show up.  Why not?  what is the best way to fix this?  It doesn't have to necessarily be exactly like this; I didn't have any luck getting this with position relative and absolute either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for clearing `float` use `overflow:hidden`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/b0v33rc0/1/

or add a `div` with styles `clear:both` before closing tag of the footer

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/b0v33rc0/2/

Comment: the clear: both; is for the stuff floated above it.  I should of been more clear about that, sorry.

Comment: no problem :) buddy add `clear:both` and `overflow:hidden` @imnothardcore

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/what-does-the-css-rule-clear-both-do this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I was about to write the same as Vitorino Fernandes has written.

However you could  also write like given below;

**HTML**

```
<footer>
<div>
<p id="p1"> Derp1</p>
<p id="p2> Derp2</p>
</div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
 footer{
    width:100%;
    background: #113551;
    }

    footer > div{
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    }

    #p1{
    float:left;
    }
    #p2{
    float:right;
    }
```

What i have done is that I only used one `div` as a container of `<p>`.

Comment: when I tried this the footer color did not show up.

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to add background color.. Now it is added. Check it out

Comment: I will have to experiment with this as well.  thanks!