# Divs not aligning (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I am having extreme difficulty organizing two divs.

I have a footer, which includes **two** paragraphs. I want `paragraph 1` hugging the left border of the footer div, and I want `paragraph 2` hugging the right border of the footer div, **AND** these paragraphs must be on the same line.

My problem is that my divs are behaving oddly.

I have tried floating and giving widths but nothing seems to work, the paragraphs seem to keep piling on top of eachother.

Does anybody know how to resolve this? I just want to know how to write 2 paragraphs out on the same line hugging opposite borders.

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
   <div id='footer'>
        <div id="errors">
          <p>paragraph 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="other">
          <p>paragraph 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container
{
   width:90%;
   margin:auto;
   background-color:#F6F4F1;
   border: 5px solid #00b4b4;
   padding:0;
   border-radius: 25px;
}

#footer
{
   width:100%;
   bottom:0;
   color:#838B8B;
   font-family:verdana;
}

#errors
{
   margin-left:4.5%;
   text-align:left;
   color:red;
}

#other
{
   text-align:right;
   margin-right:3%;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4vuywmn2/) which shows how my code is behaving oddly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made changes to your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4vuywmn2/1/

You must float the `errors` div to the left and the `other` div to right and you must `clear` after the container around them closes.

To understand why you need to `clear` I suggest you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/what-does-the-css-rule-clear-both-do/12871734#12871734)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what You want :

```css
#container
{
width:90%;
margin:auto;
background-color:#F6F4F1;
border: 5px solid #00b4b4;
padding:0;
border-radius: 25px;
}

#footer
{
width:100%;
bottom:0;
color:#838B8B;
font-family:verdana;
}

#errors
{
margin-left:4.5%;
text-align:left;
color:red;
display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

#other
{
text-align:right;
margin-right:3%;
display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

<div id='footer'>
 
   <div id="errors">
       <p>Paragraph 1</p>
   </div>
   <div id="other">
       <p>Paragraph 2</p>
   </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </div>
    
</div>
```

You have to add `display:inline-block;` for `error` class, and using `float` : `left` for error, and `right` for other. And, on end, after other, You have to add one more div with `clear:both;`, how above div float will be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Try float and position attributes like this...

```
 #container
    {
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#F6F4F1;
    border: 5px solid #00b4b4;
    padding:0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    }

    #footer
    {
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    color:#838B8B;
    font-family:verdana;
    }

    #errors
    {
    margin-left:4.5%;
    text-align:left;
    color:red;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    }

    #other
    {
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:3%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    }
```

Comment: you may change the value of left and right pixel value according to your needs...

Answer (score 0):

try this mate, is this what you want:

```
#footer
{
height: 100px;
width:100%;
bottom:0;
color:#838B8B;
font-family:verdana;
}

#errors
{
float: left;
margin-left:4.5%;
text-align:left;
color:red;
}

#other
{
    float: right;
text-align:right;
margin-right:3%;
display:inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4vuywmn2/5/