# How to explain CSS clear property?

Tags: html, css, css-float, concept

I was trying to understand [CSS clear property](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/wghd1k49/). I see that it adds a **new line** and prevents other elements from **overlapping**. I have concluded it with my personal observations and [some readings](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp).

This was something I fiddled with:

```css
.div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.div2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<h2>Using clear</h2>
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<div class="div2">div2 - remove
  <mark>clear:left</mark> and see the impact</div>
```

How can you explain this to non-programmers. Say your [wife](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=279934)?

Comment: It specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them. Have a look at the simple but detailed explanation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

Comment: @DaniMVijay I'm still [reading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12871734/2404470) :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say we have two rows, where each row has 3 chairs.

Now imagine you are sitting on the chair in the middle of first row.

If you say `clear:left`, that means you're not allowing anybody to sit to your left, likewise, if you say `clear:right`, you are not allowing anybody to sit to your right.

And if you say `clear:both` you are not allowing anybody to sit on either side and to choose the next row of chairs!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12871734/2404470) was good for programmers, not for non-programmers. I think we can explain this to our wives now ;)