# Why block elements behave like inline elements?

Tags: html, css, css-float

```css
:target {
  border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
}
.navigation li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li> <a href="#help"> Help </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#about"> About us </a> 
  </li>
</ul>

<p>lorem ipsum</p>

<br/>

<p id="help"><b> Help yourself man </b>
</p>
<p id="about"><b> We're free software lovers </b>
</p>
```

If we **inspect** the above snippet (using [dev tool](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools%5C)) `ul` and `p` elements both are `display:block` under *user agent stylesheet*. Nothing is applied in `element.style` and none of them have `float:left`

Yes, the `float` is applied to `li` **not `ul`** and removing `float:left` from `.navigation li` class will fix the problem.

`p` and `ul` both are **block** elements then why they're behaving as **inline** elements? Not adding a new line break.

I'm not looking for a fix, I need to understand the **concept** behind this.

Comment: float to the li is causing the Home and About us to be displayed inline

Comment: The real reason here is that you are *not* clearing the floats. Easiest would be to add an `overflow:hidden` to the parent i.e. the `ul` in this case. More info here - https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Comment: @Abhitalks 2 different block elements (as showing in [dev](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools%5C) tool) shall not be in single line. So, how're `ul` and `p` shown in single line. What is the concept here?

Comment: @student: From the snippet you posted in the question above, the `ul` and the `p` are not in single line. The problem which I see is that the `ul` appears after the first `p`. And that is because of the non-clearing floats. For more details about how floats affect this problem, read this - https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

Add `clear: left` to the `p` tag. This will cause it to drop below the left floated elements before it.

Use [Nicolas Gallagher's micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) on the `ul` tag:

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " "; /* 1 */
  display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

This will cause the `ul` tag to expand to the size of the `li` elements it contains.

## Explanation

The floated elements don't take up space in the document flow, so the element they are wrapped in, `ul` in this case, won't grow to take up space, so it is 0 px high.

The `p` tag comes right after the `ul`, which takes up no space, so it appears right at the top.

The `li` tags float to the left, which means they slide over to the left and push everything to their right that can be pushed over to the left. In this case, the `p` tag.

Comment: What is the point of the clearfix here? The `p { clear:left; }` alone is sufficient to get the first p element to be positioned below the floated li elements.

Comment: @Alohci I also feel that [clearfix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25343280/2404470) is better than just [`clear:left`](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/ztx0z7qc/).

Comment: @student - clearfix is not "better" than just `clear:left` but it serves a different purpose. The purpose of a clearfix is to extend the bottom of the container element box to be at least the bottom of the last floated element it contains. This is helpful when you want to put either a background or a border on the container element. But in your example, you're doing neither.

Comment: @Alohci I'm interested in the concept. Can you explain [it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34605941/2404470)?

Comment: @student - sadly no. The problem is that your understanding of "inline" is wrong. An inline box is a box that is laid out inside a line box, which is different from the concept of boxes being laid out next to one another horizontally. Floated elements are not laid out in line boxes and are therefore not "inline". You need a solid grounding in the box model and *normal flow* first, Then you can learn how floated elements are taken out of that flow and how line boxes, but not non-cleared block boxes, avoid the floated elements.

Comment: @Alohci the reason I included the clearfix is that the original question asked "`p` and `ul` both are **block** elements then why they're behaving as **inline** elements?" The clearfix will make the `ul` _appear_ more block-like. Maybe not necessary, but could help in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yup

Remove `Float:left` from `.navigation li` class

Hi student,

`li` not behaving like an inline element, it's `Block` element Itself. if a Block element with `Float:left` always align back to back.

http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/

From this Clearly you can understand what exactly a inline and Block element

Comment: +1 for this answer. However, I know how removing this will fix the problem but my question is about `in-lining` of two `block` elements.

Comment: @student  Here is my Updation

Comment: but if we inspect, `ul` and `p` both are `display:block` and none of them is `float:left`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all of the elements inside the `ul` are floated, so the `ul` behaves as if it has no content.

One solution, if you want the `li`s to remain on a single line, would be to use `display: inline` instead of `float: left` on them.

```css
:target {
  border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
}

.navigation li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li> <a href="#help"> Help </a>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#about"> About us </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<br/>
<p id="help"><b> Help yourself man </b></p>
<p id="about"><b> We're free software lovers </b></p>
```

Comment: So if you `float` elements inside a `block` element it makes the container empty? How?

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a clear:left style after the Floated li that will solve the problem.