# How to define different "text-align"s for different blocks in a single mother block?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Assume I have this codes:

```
<div class="mother">
    <div class="r">r
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="l">l
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="r">r
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="l">l
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.r {
    display: inline;
}
.l {
    display: inline;
}
```

I want all of the `.r` `<div>`s to be rendered at the right side of `.mother` and all of the `.l` `<div>`s at the left side. something like `float: right/left;`

but I don't want to use `float`. I want to use a smart `text-align`.

I tried `text-align; right/left;` for `.mother` but all of them will have the same align, all left or all right. **How can I tell `.mother` that your `text-align` must be `left` for `.l`s and `right` for `.r`s?**

Comment: something like [this](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/RrpddB)? - I just removed the `display:inline`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `display:inline` - `text-align` won't work here because the width of the element shrinks to fit the text - so there's no room to align anything.

### [Codepen demo using `text-align`](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/RrpddB)

```css
.r {
  text-align: right;
}
.l {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="mother">
  <div class="r">r
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="l">l
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="r">r
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="l">l
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way of doing this (without floats or absolute positioning) is with flexbox (NB: This method should only be used if - for some reason - the above method is inadequate)

### [Codepen demo using `flexbox`](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/wMJOZZ)

```css
.mother {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.r {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="mother">
  <div class="r">r
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="l">l
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="r">r
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="l">l
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```css
.mother{width:200px}
.r {
    display: table;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
.l {
    display: table;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mother">
    <div class="r">r
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="l">l
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="r">r
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="l">l
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `display: table;`? what is that?

Answer (score 0):

You css is wrong. Use .before r and l as it is class. And give `float:left`  to `.l` and `float:right` to `.r`.

```css
.l {
    float: left;
}
.r, .l {
    display: inline;
}

.r {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="mother">
    <div class="r">r
    </div>
    <div class="l">l
    </div>
    <div class="r">r
    </div>
    <div class="l">l
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05bvg8Lc/)**

Comment: Is there anyway **without float**? :( I mean using `text-align` but the smart way I told.

Comment: So, i think you should use `position:absolute` and should make changes in html.

Answer (score 0):

change display to inline-block

```
.r, .l {
    display: inline-block;
}
.l {
    float: left;
}
.r {
    float: right;
}
```

and clear float of div.mother

```
.mother:after{
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
    .r,.l {
        display: inline;
        clear:both;}

    .r {float:right;}
    .l {float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="mother">
    <div class="r">
    Right
    </div>
    <div class="l">
    Left
    </div>
    <div class="r">
    Right
    </div>
    <div class="l">
    Left
    </div>
</div>
```

When you float the elements, left or to the right, it creates an empty space on the other side which allows other elements to take up the remaining space.
The clear property specifies on which sides of an element floating elements are not allowed to float.

and also read this: [What does the CSS rule clear: both do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/what-does-the-css-rule-clear-both-do)

Comment: `float: left/right;` has no effect on `display: inline;` elements!  and your snippet is empty.