# div wrapping other content

Tags: html, css, margins

I seem to have a problem with one `div` wrapping other content.

If I bring some additional HTML elements between the 3 `p` elements and the `div`, it works just fine.

However, when I place them as shown in the code below, it appears that the `.disc`wraps the 3 `p` elements - i.e. they appear inside the `div`.

I had the 3 `p` elements in their own `div` as well, and yet, they would show up as part of the "disc" class.

Initially, I was specifying a complete all-round `margin`. Then, while looking for a cause to this problem, I came across collapsed margins. So, I've changed my `margin` to reflect only top and left values, but that doesn't seem to be solving the problem either.

Why is this happening?

```css
.abbr {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 15px 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.disc {
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
#discHeader {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#discHeaderLine {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p class="abbr">Line 1</p>
<p class="abbr">Line 2</p>
<p class="abbr">Line 3</p>

<div class="disc">
  <p id="discHeader"><strong>ABC</strong></p>
  <p class="clear line" id="discHeaderLine"></p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some more text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>final text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Clear your floats. https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: For reference, see [What does the CSS rule clear: both do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/what-does-the-css-rule-clear-both-do).

Comment: actually no need to clear, because OP is using `inline-block` in the same rule

Comment: @showdev , DaniP thank you :)

Comment: @thekkm13 you went for the not so good approach, against the easiest/better one?

Comment: @dippas I really liked your answer as well and it's probably the better one or maybe even more correct. The only reason I went with the other answer is because I wasn't sure what the box-sizing does (I'm sorry, I'm still very new to html-css) and the other answer had me only adding one line to my existing code.

Comment: @dippas That being said, I definitely intend to get home today and have a look at what box-sizing: border-box does and if it is a better solution to my problem, when I have some free time.

Comment: if is only because of that, here is it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing, I can add that to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `abbr` elements are floated. Add `clear: both;` to `.disc`:

```css
.abbr {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 15px 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.disc {
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  clear: both;
}
#discHeader {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#discHeaderLine {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p class="abbr">Line 1</p>
<p class="abbr">Line 2</p>
<p class="abbr">Line 3</p>

<div class="disc">
  <p id="discHeader"><strong>ABC</strong></p>
  <p class="clear line" id="discHeaderLine"></p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some more text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>final text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked fine after adding clear: both. Thank you so much! One additional minor issue - I'm specifying margins top and left for the p elements and the disc div, but there is no vertical spacing between the p blocks and the div. I can workaround by adding margin-bottom for the p blocks, but not sure why the margin-top for the div didn't create the gap in the first place.

Comment: It has to do with the float status -  the "clear" element obviously ignores margin-top below floated elements. In general I would recommend to erase the float and clear settings completely - it will work as you want it since you already made the `p` elements inline-blocks with a definied width, which is kind of similar to the float behaviour (exception: there will never be two elements beside one other element, which is possible with float). If you do that, all margins will work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

### your issue

you are using [`float:left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

### explanation + usual solution

> The `float` CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from
>   the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

Because it is taken out of the normal flow you need to clear it, using [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) property.

> The `clear` CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to
>   floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared)
>   below them. The clear property applies to both floating and
>   non-floating elements.
>
> The `float`s that are relevant to be cleared are the earlier `float`s
>   within the same block formatting context.

---

### specific solution for your problem

if you are using `inline-block`, you don't need `float:left`, because `inline-block` makes the element a block level element and `float:left` makes the element a block element as well.

Therefore no need to clear anything.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
.wrap {
  margin-left: 2em
}
.abbr {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100%/3);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-weight: 700
}
.disc {
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
#discHeader {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#discHeaderLine {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p class="abbr">Line 1</p><!--
--><p class="abbr">Line 2</p><!--
--><p class="abbr">Line 3</p>
</div>
<div class="disc">
  <p id="discHeader"><strong>ABC</strong>
  </p>
  <p class="clear line" id="discHeaderLine"></p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some more text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>final text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to include an explanation of why the OP's issue is happening, in addition to your alternative (and arguably simpler) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way to clear the float.

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
.content {
 display:inline-block;
 width:100%;
}
.content p {
 float:left;
 width:28%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: white;
 border: 2px solid black;
 margin: 15px 2%;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.disc {
 width:96%;
 margin:2em auto 0 auto;
 border: 2px solid black;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: white;
}
#discHeader {
 font-weight: bold;
}
#discHeaderLine {
 border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Line 1</p>
  <p>Line 2</p>
  <p>Line 3</p>
</div>
<div class="disc">
  <p id="discHeader"><strong>ABC</strong></p>
  <p class="clear line" id="discHeaderLine"></p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some more text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>final text</p>
</div>
```