# Html/css display two div on the same line don't work

Tags: html, css

I've started to learn some html/css/javascript for fun and i'm stuck with a problem. 
In the html I want to display some pair of div on the same line, but i don't know why i can't do it.

The div that i want to show on the same line and at the same height are the couples of "button" and "text"

Here is my code!

```css
html {
  background-color: #e6eeff;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#bgCal {
  background-color: #004466;
  color: white;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#display {
  background-color: #d7d7c1;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#numberTot {
  background-color: #d7d7c1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.button {
  background-color: #0099e6;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text {
  background-color: #004466;
  color: white;
  height: 60px;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 10px 50px 10px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="bgCal">
  <div id="display">
    <span id="numberTot"> 0 </span>
  </div>
  <button class="button" onclick="numberClick(1)">+</button>
  <div class="text">
    Every click increase of 1 the total number.
  </div>
  <br>
  <button class="button" onclick="buyStudent()">
    Buy Student
    <br>Cost: <span id="studentLUCost">10</span>
    <br>Students owned: <span id="studentLevel">0</span>
  </button>
  <div class="text">
    A student can click instead of yourself, but they are slower.
    <br>
    <span id="studentProd">0</span> num/sec
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to read float, but yes people will say display:inline-block is better so depend on condition/requirement.

Comment: @Leothelion Beat me to it. :(

Comment: hahaha you can give working example but i have readymade ex..go ahead :)

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/1spmqahg/

Comment: @DrewKennedy if you are going to use float then let me know so i can post as detailed information which is must use while using float.

Answer (score 3):

As `Leo the lion` suggested in the comments, you can simply put `float:left` and `clear:both` on your `.button` class to get the desired effect.

[`Clear`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control) is used to prevent floating elements from residing beside the element specified, in this case `both` left and right, and would push them below. There's an excellent QA about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/what-does-the-css-rule-clear-both-do) if you want to learn more.

```css
html {
    background-color: #e6eeff;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

* {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#bgCal {
    background-color: #004466;
    color: white;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#display {
    background-color: #d7d7c1;
    color: black;
    text-align: right;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    line-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#numberTot {
    background-color: #d7d7c1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.button {
    background-color: #0099e6;
    width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

.text {
    background-color: #004466;
    color: white;
    height: 60px;
    width: 180px;
    margin: 10px 50px 10px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="bgCal">
            <div id="display">
                <span id="numberTot"> 0 </span>
            </div>
            <button class="button" onclick="numberClick(1)">+</button>
            <div class="text">
                Every click increase of 1 the total number.
            </div>
            <br>
            <button class="button" onclick="buyStudent()">
                Buy Student
                <br>
                Cost: <span id="studentLUCost">10</span>
                <br>
                Students owned: <span id="studentLevel">0</span>
            </button>
            <div class="text">
                A student can click instead of yourself, but they are slower.
                <br>
                <span id="studentProd">0</span> num/sec
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Upvoted but still m trying to give example with display:inline-block too so op can learn both things :)

Comment: No need - was going to put that in too and GCyrillus was just too quick.

Comment: Hahahah everyone is too quick..try to speed up :p

Comment: one point to mention. Please use clear:both after float and put some information on that too so op will be careful with that too.

Comment: Thanks also for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `inline-block`, take a look at [`vertical-align`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align)

```css
html {
  background-color: #e6eeff;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#bgCal {
  background-color: #004466;
  color: white;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#display {
  background-color: #d7d7c1;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#numberTot {
  background-color: #d7d7c1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.button {
  background-color: #0099e6;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align:top;/* reset here vertical-align to next inline content: top, bottom, middle, 1em, etc ... */
}
.text {
  background-color: #004466;
  color: white;
  height: 60px;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 10px 50px 10px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="bgCal">
  <div id="display">
    <span id="numberTot"> 0 </span>
  </div>
  <button class="button" onclick="numberClick(1)">+</button>
  <div class="text">
    Every click increase of 1 the total number.
  </div>
  <br>
  <button class="button" onclick="buyStudent()">
    Buy Student
    <br>Cost: <span id="studentLUCost">10</span>
    <br>Students owned: <span id="studentLevel">0</span>
  </button>
  <div class="text">
    A student can click instead of yourself, but they are slower.
    <br>
    <span id="studentProd">0</span> num/sec
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow..thats what i was trying. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

in css for both `.button` and `.text` classes.

I have made a fiddle link. You can check it - https://jsfiddle.net/1fm1cpqh/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Just add float:left to your .button class
.button{
float:left;}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Appreciate it, please vote up for me on the left side. thanks in advace!