# CSS list float left

Tags: html, css

[image]
Not aligned, This is my code:

HTML:

```
    <li><div class="card">
        <img src="uploads/image/default_profile.jpg" width="195" height="260" />
        <p><strong>Dr./BGen. Antonio L. Tamayo</strong><br>
<strong>AFP, FPCHA, Ph. D</strong></p>
        <p>Chairman of the Board and CEO<br>
Founder, University of Perpetual Help System DALTA</p>
    </div></li>

    <li><div class="card">
        <img src="uploads/image/default_profile.jpg" width="195" height="260" />
        <p><strong>Daisy M. Tamayo</strong><br><strong>RN, MAN, Ph. D</strong></p>
        <p>Vice Chairman and Treasurer<br>
Co-Founder, University of Perpetual Help System DALTA</p>
    </div></li>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.card-wrap
padding: 0

li
    font-size: 16px
    display: inline-block

.card
    width: 195px
```

but when i put float: left on my CSS this happened:
[image]

it aligned but it got out of the container

```
ul.card-wrap
padding: 0

li
    float: left
    font-size: 16px
    display: inline-block

.card
    width: 195px
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: no sorry, i can't

Comment: Try to look her: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/what-does-the-css-rule-clear-both-do

Comment: Thanks it works :D

Answer (score 1):

you need `clearfix` with floats also `float: left` on the `.card-wrap`

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

read this [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8554054/3049893)

If you have the option always use **flexbox**

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
li {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

(and no float)

In your CSS, `li`s are defined as inline-blocks, which by default are vertically aligned to their baseline. This rule aligns them at their top.