# "Clear" property in CSS

Tags: css, css-float

i really have problems understanding how to use the `clear` property. I understand every other concept so far but i have trouble wrapping my head around this. does someone have an in detail description from own experience and maybe pictures to clearly explain it?

~o.k

Comment: This is a very good reference
http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/what-does-the-css-rule-clear-both-do