# CSS: Position header to the left of content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align my headers to the left of my content (see below).

[image]

I attempt to do this with the following CSS:

```
h4{
    font-family: 'Cera GR Medium', Fallback, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: .75rem;
    color: #F38181;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
}

p{
    float:right;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 650px;
}
```

This results with the following layout:
[image]

The "Skills" heading is appearing before the p element ends and the heading spacing seems independent from the p element.

HTML Code:

```
<h4>BACKGROUND</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse at nibh egestas, consequat dui ac, sagittis dolor. Suspendisse
  mollis ipsum ac orci vulputate interdum. Etiam id laoreet ligula. Sed nec est maximus, lobortis urna sit amet, molestie
  purus. Donec tristique tempus quam, in cursus erat lacinia ut. Duis tempor justo et pharetra laoreet. Phasellus maximus,
  nunc lobortis ultrices maximus, purus justo bibendum erat, ut tincidunt elit urna eu purus. Donec at mauris pretium, pulvinar
  mi at, pretium velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ut nulla eu justo </p>
<h4>SKILLS</h4>
```

Comment: where is the html code?

Comment: Add your html code too

Comment: @Viira updated the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the CSS rule "clear: both" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/what-does-the-css-rule-clear-both-do). If you investigate into how to clear floats you should be able to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

You have to enclose the title and contents inside a div which floats as well.

```css
h4{
    font-family: 'Cera GR Medium', Fallback, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: .75rem;
    color: #F38181;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
    text-align: right;
  height:auto;
    width: 19%;
    float:left;
  border:none;
}

p{
    float:right;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 80%;
border:none;
}
```

```html
<div style='float:left'><h4>BACKGROUND</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse at nibh egestas, consequat dui ac, sagittis dolor. Suspendisse
  mollis ipsum ac orci vulputate interdum. Etiam id laoreet ligula. Sed nec est maximus, lobortis urna sit amet, molestie
  purus. Donec tristique tempus quam, in cursus erat lacinia ut. Duis tempor justo et pharetra laoreet. Phasellus maximus,
  nunc lobortis ultrices maximus, purus justo bibendum erat, ut tincidunt elit urna eu purus. Donec at mauris pretium, pulvinar
  mi at, pretium velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ut nulla eu justo </p>
</div>

<div style='float:left'>
  <h4>SKILLS</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse at nibh egestas, consequat dui ac, sagittis dolor. Suspendisse
  mollis ipsum ac orci vulputate interdum. Etiam id laoreet ligula. Sed nec est maximus, lobortis urna sit amet, molestie
  purus. Donec tristique tempus quam, in cursus erat lacinia ut. Duis tempor justo et pharetra laoreet. Phasellus maximus,
  nunc lobortis ultrices maximus, purus justo bibendum erat, ut tincidunt elit urna eu purus. Donec at mauris pretium, pulvinar
  mi at, pretium velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ut nulla eu justo </p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{width:100%}
h4{
    font-family: 'Cera GR Medium', Fallback, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: .75rem;
    color: #F38181;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
}

p{
    float:right;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h4>BACKGROUND</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse at nibh egestas, consequat dui ac, sagittis dolor. Suspendisse
  mollis ipsum ac orci vulputate interdum. Etiam id laoreet ligula. Sed nec est maximus, lobortis urna sit amet, molestie
  purus. Donec tristique tempus quam, in cursus erat lacinia ut. Duis tempor justo et pharetra laoreet. Phasellus maximus,
  nunc lobortis ultrices maximus, purus justo bibendum erat, ut tincidunt elit urna eu purus. Donec at mauris pretium, pulvinar
  mi at, pretium velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ut nulla eu justo </p>
 </div> 
<div>
    <h4>SKILLS</h4>
</div>
```